# Performing a repeated async operation in Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a function `tick` that I wish to perform repeatedly. Each time `tick` completes, I want to trigger it again in `3000` ms time. If `tick` fails, I want to pause for an extra `1000` ms and then try again. I cannot use `setInterval` because I do not know how long `tick` will take to complete.

Here is my code for achieving this:

```
const loop = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Starting operation... ');
    await tick();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
  setTimeout(loop, 3000);
};

loop();
```

Unfortunately, this stops working after several days of operation. I think that I am doing something wrong with the stack.

What is the recommended way of running an `async` operation like this in Node.js?

Comment: [A Promise is an object representing the eventual completion or failure of an asynchronous operation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: @AjAX. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your current function runs the loop every 3 seconds no matter if it fails or not.

I rewrote it a bit. This should work

```
const loop = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Starting operation... ');
        await tick();
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
}

loop()
```

The above code would have the following order:

- first run tick()
- if tick() succeeds, run loop again in 3 seconds
- if tick() fails, run loop again in 1 second